# Global.asax Application_BeginRequest not firing After reinstall Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

In windows server 2012 R I formatter server and reinstall server 2012 R with IIS 8.5xx version
  I copy same file but my website does not work
Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method not firing
my application pool is integrated v4.0 I changed it to classic but it does not work

Comment: Can you elaborate **does not work**? Please add more details like the error that is seen on the page.

Comment: in global.asax _BeginRequest method there is code for redirect www for non www URL but this code does not firing,does not run does not work after  upgrade IIS 7 to IIS 8.5

Comment: Have you tried using URL Rewrite for that? It is much more easier. Also have you tried debugging ?

Comment: No..I must use global asax application begin request with IIS 8.5

Comment: please include the code so that it can be reviewed.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?