# IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite non-www to www not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I upgrade my IIS to IIS 8.5  and in IIS 8.5 global asax begin request not firing(I asked here: [Global.asax Application_BeginRequest not firing After reinstall Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060505/global-asax-application-beginrequest-not-firing-after-reinstall-server?noredirect=1#comment77099976_45060505)  )

In global asax begin request I check if URL is non www.If it is non www I just redirect to www...But begin request not firing in IIS 8.5

I searched google there is HTTP redirect module 
[image]

I tried this but it still does not work
It does not redirect non www to www
it give that error in non www

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just forget to add non www version to IIS website bindings via http://yazilimsozluk.com/http-error-404